# Megaraid storage manager. How to add drive in RAID 0 with OS

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, megaraid-storage-manager

I have a LSI megaraid sas 9271-8i controller and 8 physical drive.
I have error on Slot 0. Media count error: 1568 and Pred fail error: 12.
And I have error such as:

How can I check a partition of physical disk in MegaRaid Storage Managment? I think it's a partition with OS.

[image: Drive group]

Can i add a drive in group to create RAID 1 to mirrored OS without crash, and what about boot sector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add disks to RAID 0 without deleting all data.

You cannot replace a disk in RAID 0 without data loss.

Judging by the picture you only have RAID 0's meaning there is no redundancy anywhere.

You could delete some of these RAID 0 and create RAID 1s to have redundancy but you will have half the speed and capacity. In RAID 1 you will be able to replace a failed disk with no data loss occurring.